# Having an optional prefix in ember routes

Tags: ember.js

### Problem

The app has to have root prefix that is optional. The prefix also has a dynamic segment.

### Example

The content of

> /posts/1 and /account/123/posts/1 has to load the **same** route and template.

where /account/123 is the prefix. 123 is a **dynamic segment of the prefix**.

### Requirement

1. All the urls has to be accessible **with and without** the prefix.
2. When prefix route is loaded , all single page transitions has to be in context of prefix-urls.

   > /account/123/post/1 to /account/123/post/2
3. When non-prefix route is loaded , all single page transitions has to be in context of non-prefix-urls.

   > /post/1 to /post/2

### Constraints

1. The existing codebase has routes without the **prefix urls**.
2. As controllers,routes,tempaltes **already exist** in routes **without prefix** , the solution has to reuse the existing code.

### Expected Solution

1. All functions making spa transitions **has to see the window.location context** and make transition to prefix or non-prefix path. This will include functions as transitionTo,replaceWith,linkTo helper,etc

   > Since the existing **link-to helper**,etc, will have route name as post.detail (**non-prefix routes**)
2. Has to have minimal code changes in the existing controller , routes, templates.

### Example of Existing Routes

```
NewRouter.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('detail',{path: "/:id"});

    this.route('comments', function() {
        this.route('detail',{path: "/:id"});
    });
  });

});
```

The controllers, routes, templates **already exist** for post, post.detail, comments, comment.detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ember router has a property `rootURL`. If you wanted to serve a blogging application from http://emberjs.com/blog/, it would be necessary to specify a root URL of `/blog/`.

This can be achieved by configuring the rootURL property on ENV:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-blog',
    environment: environment,
    rootURL: '/blog/',
    locationType: 'auto',
  };
}
```

In your case, though, this `rootURL` is dynamic. The [EmberRouter](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/EmberRouter/methods/init?anchor=init) has an init function that you could use to dynamically set this value at runtime before any urls in your application are built by dynamically inspecting the URL which is loaded.

```
export default class Router extends EmberRouter {
  init(){
    super.init(...arguments);
    // trailing slash is required for rootURL
    let acctsSubUrl = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/accounts\/\d+\//);
    if(acctsSubUrl){
      this.rootURL = acctsSubUrl[0];
    }
  }
  location = config.locationType;
  rootURL = config.rootURL;
}
```

If you do this, let your default `ENV` value for `rootURL` be `/`. This should solve your requirement of a dynamic prefix that loads for **all** route urls when present. I tested this against Ember 3.17 and it works

Comment: Ember dev server does not serve index.html, unless the we specify the prefix in rootUrl variable. I actually have a proxy setup to force serve index.html. Is there any other workaround or config in dev server ?

Comment: I tested this exact setup locally. What version of ember are you using?

Comment: I am using Ember version 3.3. Seems like there is a way to config ember dev -server https://blog.201-created.com/secrets-of-the-ember-cli-server-bde80bb546dd.

How were able to test in local since /accounts/123/posts will give 404 by the ember dev-server. Did you do by overriding in server/index.js

Before knowing about server/index.js, I had a proxy in local itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a right answer for this. I see a couple of options here, but before taking them be very certain you actually needed the account info in the URL and it can't just be stored in a service.

I think the best option would be to just create routes in both places and then duplicate the needed component tree. You're going to have a bit of code duplication, which is probably an OK price to pay for having less to worry about.

```
//posts/detail/index.hbs
`<PostDetail @id={{@model.id}} @accountId={{null}} />
```

```
//account/posts/detail/index.hbs
`<PostDetail @id={{@model.id}} @accountId={{@model.account}} />
```

You might also try using [engines](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines) and mounting the same route twice (once at each URL), but engines comes with it's own set of challenges.